# kitchen-counter light replacement

Tags: lighting, kitchens, light

I have a tube light above my kitchen's electric cooking range . It is a Philips light that has "F15T8/CW/24" written on it. I think that it's [this product](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002CYW406).

Are the below guesses correct?

1. "F15" means 15 watts.
2. "24" means 24-inch length.

What does "T8" mean?

Would it be possible to provide a higher-watt alternative? I would prefer an Amazon link. I've tried to search but didn't get good results.

update 1--------------------------------------------------------------------

I was able to get 24 watts tube light for the same set up. I bought it from the local Lowe's

Comment: T-8 refers to bulb diameter (and pin arrangement). No you will not find "higher watt" alternatives. But you may find different temperature (color) bulbs and you *may* be able to retrofit an LED replacement that is brighter.

Comment: i want to keep Cool white color. in such do i have to replace entire fixture?

Comment: It's above a cooking range, LED may dislike the heat.

Comment: Does the light buzz or flicker?

Comment: Light bulb numbering is actually pretty standard in the USA, in this case:  F means Fluorescent, 15 is the wattage, T is the lamp shape (tube in this case), the number following the Lamp shape in this case 8 is the diameter of the lamp in 1/8 inch increments which in this case 8/8th = 1 inch.  As others have said lumens are a better measure of light quantity, and changing the color temp of the light will change perceived brightness, if you like "cool white" try 50k and you may find the color temp is just as pleaseing but appears brighter.

Comment: Actually the T8 stands for an 8 mm radius, T5 5 mm and T12 12mm etc.

Comment: @RetiredMasterElectrician: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescent-lamp_formats), the same tube is sometimes known as a T8 (8/8 inch diameter) and sometimes known as a T26 (26mm diameter). Where I live I only ever see the "traditional" designations based on eighths of an inch.

Answer (score 3):

> **are below guesses correct?**

Different manufacturers use different systems for identifying products. You shouldn't look for products by that exact code unless you are not interested in products from other manufacturers and have no problems with product availability.

For a straight fluorescent tube, the key things you need to know, in approximate decreasing order of importance) include

- connector types (usually bi-pin)
- diameter (in eighths of an inch)
- length (in feet or in metric equivalent for many folk outside USA)
- colour temperature (often expressed as cool-white, warm-white, daylight etc)
- light output (lumens) or
- power (watts) - usually proportional to length.
- voltage (Usually only one variant e.g. 120V in USA, 230V in EU)

If you ask for an "two-foot warm-white T8 fluorescent-tube" you'll most likely get something that does the job.

> **what does t8 mean?**

As Jimmy stated, it refers to the diameter of the tube in eighths of an inch. The T8 designation is for fluorescent tubes with two pins at each end.

> **would it be possible to provide higher watt alternative?**

Generally no. You usually need a longer tube to produce more light.

Note that nowadays, wattage is useless as an indication of light output, you should look for lumens instead. Wattage just tells you how much heat the tube (or bulb) puts out.

Fluorescent tubes are still pretty good at light output. In my local store recently, the tubular LED fixtures had lower light output than the same sized (but cheaper) fluorescent fixtures. The key is to always check or compare the light output rating in lumens.